# div higher up tree does not receive click 'through' lower div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains another div. They are both dynamically created with some data pulled by an ajax request.

I have a click event that I'd like to attach to both the outer and inner div, but for some reason when i click on the area chrome renders in blue in the first image below, nothing happens

[image: chrome inspects divs]

And here is the structure in the html pane

[image: html of div content]

This is the function which does the event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').click(function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('#INT-note')) {
            if (!$('#INT-note').hasClass('expanded_note')) {
                $('#INT-note').addClass('expanded_note');

                $('#INT-note').animate({
                    height: '300',
                    width: '200',
                    overflow: 'scroll'
                }, 500, function () {

                    $('#INT-note_text').fadeIn(100);
                });

            } else {

                $('#INT-note').removeClass('expanded_note');
                $('#INT-note_text').fadeOut(100);
                $('#INT-note').animate({
                    height: '45',
                    width: '45',
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                }, 500, function () {
                    //console.log('test');
                });
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Is there some way I can make the lower div receive clicks through the 'top-level' div, so that I don't have so do like `$('#lower, .upper')` or something?

`[pointer-events:none;][3]` hasn't worked for me so far,because it seems to fire click functions on divs below the one I want clicked. I'd like just to go down one level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with the event binding, because the `div`s are dynamiclly inserted, use [`On`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead `click` on the body, so It will attach the event automatically to new elements inserted.

```
 $('body').on('click',function (event) {
     //same code
 });
```

Comment: ok. thank you. so `on` is just `$(document).ready(function () { $('body').on('click, function (event) {  if (event.is('#INT-note')) { etc etc ` ?

Comment: that is the same problem. click does not get through to the div, unfortunately.

Comment: you question is not clear to me, do you want to run the code inside if condition when either inner div or outer div being clicked??

Answer (score 0):

You can't use normal `click` or `bind` with dynamically added content, try `live`, `delegate` or the more recent `on`.

Comment: just a heads up - live is deprecated as of 1.7

Comment: Oh, but it still works fine for me. But `on` is of course more preferable.